# Replacing line breaks

Tags: php, html

I've got a html form with a textarea. After submitting the form I'd like single line breaks, `"\n"` to be replaced by `"<br />"` and double line breaks, "\n\n", by `"</p><p>"`. I've tried with str_replace but that does not have the desired effect.

str_replace("\n", `"<br /"`, $string) has the undersired effect of adding `"<br />"` even after heads (`<h1>`) or within lists ("`<li>`"). Is there a solution?

Comment: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: "and double line breaks, "\n\n", by "</p><p>"" That does not solve this.

Comment: @Coenj see my answer bellow to solve the `\n\n` issue

Answer (score 0):

Submit the textarea using:

```
nl2br($_POST['textareaname'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(\<br(\s*)?\/?\>(\s*)?){2}/i', '</p><p>', nl2br($_POST['textareaname']));
```

First it will replace `\n` by `<br/>` and then double `<br/>` (or `<br>` or `<br />` and space between by `</p><p>`

Comment: the str_replace is not working. The double breaks are not being replaced.

Comment: Isn't it possible to replace \n only where it is followed by a letter (a-z) or number?

Comment: Yes it is but here I am doing the work for you while you're not even searching...